# Can't connect to my Yaesu FT5D on Windows, what could be the problem?

Tags: yaesu, computer-control, windows

I installed the driver that Yaesu offers, name PL23XX_Prolific_DriverInstaller_v402, and I'm plugging it to a USB port in my computer using the cable that came with the Yaesu FT5D and then I get this error:

[image]

and I'm pretty sure it's this device in the Device Manager:

[image]

Any ideas what to do here?

Comment: Make sure it’s the right device by removing it and replacing it with Device Manager open then try uninstalling the it and letting it be rediscovered if needed

Comment: I have the same problem and on different computers. Could you solve the problem?

Comment: Hi @MauricioFarias, welcome to the site! You should up-vote the question if you're also interested in the answer. Up-voting helps raise the profile of the question in the community, which also increases probability for a helpful answer.

Answer (score 1):

This specific error says:

> A request for the USB device descriptor has failed

In other words, the USB device did not respond to being asked what it is. (see how the device manager can't even say what the device ID and vendor ID are? It just refers to the device by its position on a (potentially internal) USB hub.

Since that's necessary to even set up communication with a device on an electrical level, nothing can work from here.

There's two things that might have gone wrong:

- broken cable (that's literally the most common reason), missing components on the device, or
- completely disfunctional USB stack on the device.

In both cases, a hardware issue that we can't help you solve.